# How to add an attribute to a collection marked with XmlArrayAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML of the format like here: http://pastie.org/1311506 (not inserting it here because comment parser deletes tags).

This XML is serealized/deserialized using the following code:

```
[XmlRoot("products")]
public class Products
{
    [XmlElement("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("cars")]
    [XmlArrayItem("car")]
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

var products = new Products
                   {
                       Label = "1",
                       Cars = new[]
                                  {
                                      new Car {Name = "BMW"},
                                      new Car {Name = "Volvo"}
                                  }
                   };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Products));
var writer = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(writer, products);
Console.WriteLine(writer);
```

I need an additional attribute to `<cars>` node called `type` (like here: http://pastie.org/1311514). How can I do it?

In other words, how to define data classes (Products and Car and maybe others if necessary) in order to parse XML of the format shown in the second pastie link?

Comment: "parser deletes tags": not if you format it as code (indent by 4 spaces or use Ctrl+K)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that, because for collections the `XmlSerializer` ignores all members, it only serializes the items of the collection. However, if you only want to deserialize it and ignore the `type` attribute, it's not an issue : unknown attributes will just be ignored.

If you need to get the value of `type`, you can declare a class that is not a collection, but contains the collection. Something like that:

```
public class Cars
{
    [XmlElement("car")]
    public Car[] Items { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

In your `Products` class, just declare the `Cars` property of type `Cars` with just a `XmlElement` attribute:

```
[XmlRoot("products")]
public class Products
{
    [XmlElement("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cars")]
    public Cars Cars { get; set; }
}
```